# List of Programs that PC ROM have, Which supports the UEFI

Tags: firmware, rom, uefi

List of programs that UEFI ROM have, And how to call them from other programs

Comment: UEFI ROM means BIOS ROM also called firmware, that comes with a computer when we purchase. where it have system startup, initialization, boot services, runtime services programs that are used when a starts or rebooted and used by other programs. what i want is the list of program, that comes when we brought a computer without a hard drive which stores third party programs or operating system. or  a way to find those list of programs?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question should be closed as off-topic, UEFI doesn't have any programs. It's UEFI Shell which provides access to utils. You can download a shell from [EDK II repository](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell). Command reference can be found in [Shell Specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_2_2.pdf)